# How to change backslash to double backslash?

Tags: c#, sql-server, string, t-sql, backslash

My TSQL query return a string like this :

`a\path\to\file.xml`

And I want to put it in a string like this :

```
string path = reader.GetString(0); (return the query result of the first field => "a\path\to\file.xml")
```

so when I want to use `path` I have got this :

```
Console.WriteLine(path); //Output : `apathtofile.xml`
```

But I want the value like : `a\path\to\file.xml`.

I already try this because i think I have to double the backslash in the string:

```
path = reader.GetString(0).Replace("\\", "\\\\");  -> do nothing

path = reader.GetString(0).Replace(@"\", @"\\\"); -> do nothing

path = Regex.Replace(reader.GetString(0), "\\", "\\\\") -> analyse de "\" - \ non conforme à la fin du modèle 

path = Regex.Replace(reader.GetString(0), @"\", @"\\\") -> analyse de "\" - \ non conforme à la fin du modèle
```

*French installation -> french error message. sory*

Comment: I don't understand. You get this `a\path\to\file.xml` string with `reader.GetString(0)` method? If so, `Console.WriteLine` doesn't write it as `apathtofile.xml` IMO.. Totally unclear what you have and what have try to do.

Comment: The question is very unclear at the moment - it doesn't look like you've got *any* backslashes in the string at the moment... and if you did have, the first result would double them, although it's not clear why you want to...

Comment: Why your TSQL returns: `a\path\to\file.xml` and WriteLine print: `apathtofile.xml`?

Comment: My query in sql server management studio return `"a\path\to\file.xml"` value, The field type is a string. In my console application I want to get the same value but when I put the value in `string path` the "\" does not interpreted like a char but like special char for something like "\n" so I want to change "\" to "\\" for, at final, I will have a value like `"a\path\to\file.xml"`and not like `"apathtofile.xml"`

Comment: @Crunchy_Artie The **only** time when you have to escape a character in a string is if you use a string literal, not when you already have a string object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query was created by another developer and he wrote this into the query:

```
REPLACE(SubQuery.PATH,'/','\')
```

I just change it to :

```
REPLACE(SubQuery.PATH,'/','\\')
```

And it's work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to options make a double backslash from a single backslash:

1. `string test = "your\\string".Replace("\\", "\\\\");`
2. `string test = "your\\string".Replace(@"\", @"\\");`

Comment: I'm sorry may be I am not clear but in your example yo have `"my\\string"` but me I have just `"my\string"` so Replace does not work because I think  this pattern : `"\\"` never match and this pattern : `"\"` it's impossible because in this case he want to use `\"`

Comment: Your confusing what comes from the database and what is in your code. In the c# code, \\ ist what the code contains, but in memory is only \. Thats the same as in your database. Thats because backslash is also an escape char in code.

Answer (score 0):

> if i undrstand it correctly- use any split function and then use
>   cursor to rebuild the string

```
--CREATE  TABLE tstr(str varchar(10))
INSERT INTO tstr
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString]('a\path\to\file.xml','\') AS fss
DECLARE @x varchar(20)=(SELECT TOP 1 str from tstr)
SELECT * FROM tstr
DECLARE   cur CURSOR
FOR SELECT str
FROM [dbo].[tstr] AS t
DECLARE @i varchar(10)
DECLARE @a varchar(100)=''
OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @i

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
SET @a=@a+@i+'\\'   
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @i
END
SELECT left(@a,len(@a)-2)

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[tstr]
```